# Install Android TV on older Sony Bravia TV

Tags: android-tv, smart-tv

I have a [Sony Bravia TV KDL-55W805B](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/kdl-55w805b) which unfortunately has Sony's own Smart TV software installed, and not Android TV which newer Sony TV's have. I am stuck with a discontinued TV software that doesn't get any updates or new apps.

Is there any way for me to install Android TV on my TV and replace the Sony Smart TV?

Answer (score 1):

No. The hardware is different and so is the kernel. It's just not supported unless one of the devs around ports it to the TV, which is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

You could use  a compatible Android TV Stick, to access similar features of other newer Sony TVs with in-built Android TV software. Most of these are available on eBay.

You can still stream through various genres:

- YouTube
- XBMC
- Netflix
- Showbox etc

You connect your Android TV stick to the HDMI input of the LED TV and make it a Smart TV

**NB Check compatibility first**